# Java - Creating an array from a series of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, creation, series

this might be a beginners question, but I am only just learning to program using java :)

I have a program that depends on plugins for it's information. When the program loads, it loads all of the plugins alongside it. I would like to make a String array filled with the contents of a String from these plugins.

All plugins have the string `getWikiName`, but all plugins have different values for the string. When this program starts up, I need to combine all of these values into an array called `wikiNameArray[]` in an orderly fashion.

```
Plugin A: getWikiName = "String1";
Plugin B: getWikiName = "String2";

End Result: wikiNameArray[] = {"String1","String2"}
```

-edit-

Here is some new code that I found that might help.

```
getWikiName.toArray(wikiNameArray)
```

But does this add the string to the next free index in the array instead of just making the array equal to getWikiName?

Comment: Do they have all share a common interface?

Comment: @Mena Well I have tried a StringBuilder, but I think that is used for Array -> String. I was thinking a for loop would be a good place to start. Let me write some code and add it to the main post.

Comment: @VaughanHilts Yes. They share a common interface

Comment: Are they in a list or do you call them manaully?

Comment: I call them through an initialization event when the program starts up. So during startup it will find all of the methods you ask it to run and run them. So yeah, they run in a list.

Comment: I don't get it. You are asking to build an array from strings but in your code you're doing the complete opposite?! BTW naming the variable *wikiNameArrayBuilder* while it's a `StringBuilder` is confusing to say the least.

Comment: @Bart I realized that. I removed the code from the OP so there isn't any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the size beforehand you can create an array and fill each cell directly:

```
String[] wikiNameArray = new String[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    wikiNameArray[i] = getWikiName();
}
```

If you don't know the size use a `List` and convert it when it contains all strings

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Wiki wiki : wikis) {
    list.add(wiki.getWikiName());
}
String[] wikiNameArray= list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Comment: The `List` might work. Thank you for the help, and sorry that my post was so confusing. I lack the skill level to post on stack overflow lol